# WordPress pagination showing extra blank page after filtering past events

Tags: wordpress, pagination, paging, custom-post-type

I have a list of events that are displaying in date order, with events in the past being hidden.

The issue is that in total, there are 3 pages of events, but once the past events are hidden, there are only enough events to fill 2 pages. However, a third, blank page is still present and can be accessed through the paging links.

This is the code on my events list page:

```
<?php $today = date("Ymd");?>

<?php $paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
query_posts( '&post_type=upcomingevents&paged=' . $paged );?> 

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'upcomingevents', 'paged'=> $paged, 'meta_key' => 'start_date', 'meta_compare' => '>=', 'meta_value' => $today, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts('post_type=upcomingevents') ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

And this is the paging code in my functions file:

```
function paginate() {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
$pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => true,
    'type' => 'plain'
);
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
echo paginate_links( $pagination );
```

}

I have also discovered a second issue, when moving to page 2 or 3 of results, the CSS class of current remains on the number 1 within the paging, so impossible to tell which page you are on.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$paged` value is `0` on 1st page so edit your first snippet:

`$paged = 0;`

also, as you're using WP_Query, you can safely delete following line, which is probably doing more wrong than good:

`query_posts( '&post_type=upcomingevents&paged=' . $paged );`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, changing the number to zero had no impact and removing the line you suggested resulted in everything breaking - got a blank page instead of my events.

Is there anything else anyone can suggest?